# For ${\bf x} = (x_1, x_2) \in R$ find ${\bf y} = (y_1, y_2)$ such that ${\bf x} = y_1{\bf v_1} + y_2{\bf v_2}$

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

For ${\bf x} = (x_1, x_2) \in R$ find ${\bf y} = (y_1, y_2)$ such that ${\bf x} = y_1{\bf v_1} + y_2{\bf v_2}$ and find a matrix $M \in M_2(R)$ such that ${\bf y} = M{\bf x}$.

How do I go about solving this question? I don't have a clue where I should be starting.

Comment: Are you told that $\mathbf{v_{1}}$ and $\mathbf{v_{2}}$ are a basis? If not you cannot in general find such $\mathbf{y}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let 
$$
\mathbf{v}_1=(v_{11}, v_{12})^\prime
$$
and 
$$
\mathbf{v}_2=(v_{21}, v_{22})^\prime.
$$
Then 
$$
\mathbf{x}=\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\end{pmatrix}=y_1\begin{pmatrix}v_{11}\\ v_{12}\end{pmatrix}+y_2\begin{pmatrix}v_{21}\\ v_{22}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}y_1v_{11}+y_2v_{21}\\y_1v_{12}+y_2v_{22}\end{pmatrix}.
$$
In other words, you have the following system of equations to solve:
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1=y_1v_{11}+y_2v_{21}\\
x_2=y_1v_{12}+y_2v_{22}.
\end{cases}
$$

Note that we can also write the original equation as:
$$
\mathbf{x}=\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{v_1}&\mathbf{v_2}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\y_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}v_{11}&v_{12}\\v_{21} & v_{22}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\ y_2\end{pmatrix}.
$$
We can call the last matrix $\mathbf{V}$ and write what we have as
$$
\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{V}\mathbf{y}
$$
Premultiply both sides by $\mathbf{V}^{-1}$ to get
$$
\mathbf{V}^{-1}\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{y}
$$
meaning that
$$
\mathbf{M}=\mathbf{V}^{-1}.
$$